# How does WordPress's custom[column] sortable hooks work?

Tags: php

**How does WordPress's custom[column] sortable hooks work?**

I have added the following code in `users.php` of the WordPress. It's working and sorting the custom columns.

```
function users_sortable_columns( $columns ) 
   {
      $columns['ID'] = 'ID';
      $columns['user_nicename'] = 'Nick Nam';
      $columns['user_url'] = 'User URL';
      return $columns;
   }

add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'users_sortable_columns' );
```

I am having no understanding how does it work.

> What this `$column['ID'] = 'ID'`

Please go through the following screenshots

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMqPC.png